# Stock footage search service

Tags: video

Is there any service where I can describe stock footage that I need using human readable search terms and sentences and send out a search request to multiple footage archives at once, so I will not have to contact each one individually, that will then use real humans or otherwise search intelligently and send me a list of suggested and relevant footage clips?

Comment: I don't know, but if there isn't you might consider Amazon http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Mechanical_Turk which is designed for this sort of work. It's not free.

Comment: yeah.  I was going to say mechanical turk.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean by human readable search terms, as opposed to keywords or tags?

But for a meta search directory service I would recommend (know of)
http://www.footage.net/
(If anyone knows of any additional search engine stock video directories, I would love to know about it as well)

Otherwise, ya, you would be going through each service looking for footage.
These are the stock services that I am aware of:
http://www.shutterstock.com/video/
http://www.gettyimages.ca/footage/ <- used by major media outlets
http://www.pond5.com/
http://www.alwayshd.com/
https://www.videocopilot.net/products/ <- geared more to adding effects to clips
http://www.footagesearch.com/

And many more... I am sure others can chime in with their favorite sites.

Answer (score 1):

I use [VideoHive](http://videohive.net/popular_item/by_category?ref=altarvic&category=stock-footage) - large collection of clips and affordable prices.